# How do you attract attention to questions on Meta, if there is no bounty to dole out?

Tags: discussion, bounty, meta

Here on Meta, we can't use bounties.

So what shall I do then, if I believe an old post of mine didn't get enough attention?

Comment: I know that feel

Comment: Because bounties aren't a thing on meta, are making trivial edits frowned upon (as much)?  I really don't know.

Comment: @ryanyuyu- Hmmmmm, well I could do that, but .. I dunno, seems like too much effort compared to if I could plop down a nice 500 rep bounty?

Comment: Rumours say it is still possible to post bounties on Meta, but it requires 750k+ reputation, ultimately making [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) the only person capable of doing it.

Comment: It makes sense in that you can't earn or lose rep on meta so there's no rep to put up for a bounty, but it does mean you're totally reliant on the community's interest in your question for its own sake. Other than edits to improve or add more info, I got nothing.

Comment: @BSMP interestingly, you can still earn the mortarboard badge on meta.

Answer (score 11):

Typically on Meta sites, there's enough viewership that a sufficient number of people will have seen your post. If a while goes by and nobody's responded, it's likely that the people who did felt it didn't need a response, or they didn't want to do it.

Still, very rarely I've seen people get really unlucky and have a Meta post Tumbleweed; if that happens, try to make a substantial edit to your post to bump it to the front page.

If you can't think of anything substantial to add, and you're absolutely sure you've made one of those rare posts, then some minor edits would be okay, too.

Comment: I like this "solution," and I'll upvote it.  I'm just not sure this is the _recommended_ course of action.  But it's better than nothing.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah, it's not ideal, agreed, but I think it's likely the best solution available.

Comment: One small corner-case.  This doesn't work for "bumping" posts you don't own if you are <2k rep since you can't suggest edits for posts on meta.  So how would a "dummy" answer be viewed?  That sounds even jankier.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm 100% positive that wouldn't be taken well.

Answer (score 8):

Link it in [The Stack Overflow Tavern](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks) or [A Meta Stack Overflow chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=meta.stackoverflow.com).